# Error on MediaPlayer.onCreate method / Android Music app

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have problem with my music app. I have made a MediaPlayer and application is crashing on this:

```
2021-08-03 22:54:09.621 6494-6494/com.example.musiclistenerremake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.musiclistenerremake, PID: 6494
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musiclistenerremake/com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)

...

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity.getIntentMethod(PlayerActivity.java:106)
        at com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:36)

...
```

Full logcat log:

```
2021-08-03 22:54:09.621 6494-6494/com.example.musiclistenerremake E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.musiclistenerremake, PID: 6494
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musiclistenerremake/com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity.getIntentMethod(PlayerActivity.java:106)
        at com.example.musiclistenerremake.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2021-08-03 22:54:15.300 6494-6509/com.example.musiclistenerremake W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

In my opinion I did initialize MediaPlayer correctly, I tried to move mediaPlayer before if statement (I don't know why I thought it will help) only, don't have idea what is wrong here.
Im using Android API 29.

```
   private void getIntentMethod() {
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        listSongs = musicFiles;
        if (listSongs != null)
        {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
        }

        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
    }
```

Here is full code of this activity (PlayerActivity):

```
package com.example.musiclistenerremake;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.example.musiclistenerremake.MainActivity.musicFiles;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView song_name, artist_name, duration_played, duration_total;
    ImageView cover_art, nextBtn, prevBtn, backBtn, shuffleBtn, repeatBtn;
    FloatingActionButton playPauseBtn;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    int position = -1;
    static ArrayList<MusicFiles> listSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    static Uri uri;
    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        initViews();
        getIntentMethod();
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mediaPlayer != null)
                {
                    int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                    duration_played.setText(formattedTime(mCurrentPosition));
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    private String formattedTime(int mCurrentPosition) {
        String totalOut = "";
        String totalNew = "";
        String seconds = String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition % 60);
        String minutes = String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition / 60);
        totalOut = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        totalNew = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
        if (seconds.length() == 1)
        {
            return totalNew;
        }
        else
        {
            return totalOut;
        }
    }

    private void getIntentMethod() {
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", -1);
        listSongs = musicFiles;
        if (listSongs != null)
        {
            playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_pause_24);
            uri = Uri.parse(listSongs.get(position).getPath());
        }

        if (mediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        song_name = findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        artist_name = findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        duration_played = findViewById(R.id.durationPlayed);
        duration_total = findViewById(R.id.durationTotal);
        cover_art = findViewById(R.id.cover_art);
        nextBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_next);
        prevBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_prev);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        shuffleBtn = findViewById(R.id.shuffle);
        repeatBtn = findViewById(R.id.id_repeat);
        playPauseBtn = findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are You sure the `uri` that is used in the `create` method is correctly initialized?

Comment: What do you mean "correctly"? I think it's correctly, but... It's just my opinion, I'm begginer with android/java, can you specify?

Comment: You can debug the application and see if the Uri contains anything.

Comment: I checked this, uri contains song path that I clicked. (uri = {Uri$StringUri@9860)} "here is path")

Answer (score 0):

Don't use     `mediaplayer.release()`
because after resetting player after  `mediaplayer.reset()`  is uninitialized state and if the player is not initialized then it will throw an exception

Comment: Please include an explanation **why**. Doing so is more helpful as it leads to understanding of the issue.